# Creating NetCDF file with mostly NaNs

Tags: c++, netcdf

I am creating a NetCDF file with mostly NaN values. Is there a way I can specify it to be compressed rather than taking up large disk space? I am using the University Corporation for Atmospheric Research C++ NetCDF library.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on which netCDF C++ API you are using, the legacy (netcdf-cxx-4.2) C++ API or the newer netcdf-cxx4-4.2 C++ API.

With the netCDF-4 C++ library, documented [here](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf/docs/cxx4/), just use the NcVar::setCompression method.

With the legacy netCDF-3 C++ library, there is no C++ method to do what you want directly.  But that library is implemented as a thin layer over the netCDF C library, so by adding an NcVar constructor that sets the compression level by calling the C function nc_def_var_deflate, it ought to be fairly straightforward.  Of course, you would have to make sure your legacy C++ library was built to use a previously installed netCDF-4 library.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it is better to produce netcdf4 compressed files at creation time, but I just wanted to add that if one already has code written that produces the file in an uncompressed way, it is possible to use CDO on existing files to convert to netcdf4 conventions and compress at the same time:

```
cdo -f nc4c -z zip_9 copy in.nc out.nc
```